# Self signed Cisco VPN Certificate

Tags: vpn, firewall, cisco, certificate

So I just rented some servers protected with a Cisco Firewall from a data center provider. I plan on accessing these servers through VPN.

The instructions from the data center provider was to download the "Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client" and uncheck the "Block connections to untrusted servers" in the VPN client.

I asked the provider if this is common practice as it seems like I am undoing the default security.

The provider has responded with that this is their normal procedure to use a self-signed certificate and the encryption security of the actual VPN tunnel is not affected.

I am worried that I may be more susceptible to man in the middle attacks as it seems like the client software will warn me that I am connecting to an untrusted host on every connect without detailing any information about the untrusted certificate.

Is this a real problem here from a security standpoint that needs to be fixed or is the provider suggested security level fine?

Comment: Is it truly self-signed? Or is it signed by the provider's CA?

Comment: I think it is truly self signed, it seems to be a root certificate

Comment: it is a matter of trust on your part. it is just as secure, as long as you have seen that cert, and you remember and trust that particular cert. the issue is when someone else (say me) try to connect to that device, i have no idea who issued the cert of it is indeed self issued and not just presented by an attacker, in my case, say, i need a third party to verify your credentials. Self signed certs are ok ONLY when you are identifying yourself to... yourself. It is a chain of trust thing, not a technology one.

Comment: Well the client software does not show any details about the cert more than that it is unknown. Which makes it impossible for me, as far as I know to know see the difference between the unknown certificate I trust from any other unknown certificate.

Comment: @OskarSjöberg crappy client. what you could do is to get a copy of the public certificate and imported to the 'trusted certificates' in your local machine.